# Codeigniter Pagination Need Solution - number link work but page doesnot display as appropriate

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I have a problem with pagination in CodeIgniter 2.x
This is my code in Controller:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'crawl/all/'.$file.'/';
$config['total_rows'] = $total;
$config['per_page'] = 10;
$config['num_links'] = 3;
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul id="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next">';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$data['total'] = $total;
$data['path'] = $this->path.'/'.$file;
$data['file'] = $file;
$data['batch'] = $this->batch->all($file, $config['per_page'], $config['uri_segment']);
```

and my view is just: `<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links() ?>`

The links for pages numbers work (they move from 1 to 2 etc), but the data does not display correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by "the data does not display correctly"? What are you expecting and what are you getting? It looks like you don't set `config['cur_page']`, which could be causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are missed out the page id because when you clicks on the page the page no has to send as query string and it has to add for the config.

Example code:

```
$limit = $this->config->item('paging_limit');
$offset = $id * $limit;

$data['rows'] = $this->news_model->get_moreNews($limit, $offset);
$config["image_url"]=$this->config->item("base_url");
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'/news/morenews/';
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('news');
$config['per_page'] = $limit;
$config['chapter'] = $this->input->post('chapter');
$config['page'] = $id;

$this->paginationsimple->initialize($config);
$paginator=$this->paginationsimple->create_links();

$data['paginator'] = $paginator;
```

Comment: thanks mr. anton, i do not understand about **$this->config->item('paging_limit')** ?